# How to ftp CodeIgniter with Netbeans?

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

I have Codeigniter and I put my system and application folder in the root directory on the website, before the www/public_html. How do I work that through Netbeans? As far as I know netbeans can only update files/folders in the public_html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In netbeans you can choose you working directory as you like [Here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html#runPHPApplicationOnRemoteServer) is a guide to do that